# Unable to use flash messages within if($_POST) condition in PhalconPHP

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have this in my Signin controller to listen for a $_POST data:

```
<?php

use \Phalcon\Tag;

class SigninController extends BaseController {

    public function indexAction()
    {
        Tag::setTitle('Login');

        // if submit
        if ($_POST) {

            $user = Users::findFirst([
                "email = :email: AND password = :password:",
                "bind" => [
                    "email"    => $this->request->getPost('email'),
                    "password" => $this->request->getPost('password')
                ]
            ]);

            if ($user) {
                $this->session->set('id', $user->id);
                $this->session->set('role', $user->role);
                $this->response->redirect("account");
            } else {
                $this->flash->error('Wrong credentials!');
                $this->response->redirect('signin');
            }

        }

    }

}
```

But the flash message with "Wrong credentials" is not being shown when I submit the form.
The page just reloads.

I have this in my base.volt template:

```
<body>

    {{ flash.output() }}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

</body>
```

and it's working for everything except if($_POST) condition.

I have this in my bootstrap file:

```
$di->set('flash', function() {
        $flash = new \Phalcon\Flash\Session([
            'error'   => 'alert alert-danger',
            'success' => 'alert alert-success',
            'notice'  => 'alert alert-info',
            'warning' => 'alert alert-warning',
        ]);
        return $flash;
    });
```

Any idea why the flash messages do not working inside my if($_POST) condition?

Comment: You should use flashSession with redirect(), not flash.

Comment: I have this in my bootstrap file: `$di->set('flash', function() {
        $flash = new \Phalcon\Flash\Session([
            'error'   => 'alert alert-danger',
            'success' => 'alert alert-success',
            'notice'  => 'alert alert-info',
            'warning' => 'alert alert-warning',
        ]);
        return $flash;
    });`

Comment: @Phantom Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Try to replace redirect with internal forward: `$this->dispatcher->forward(array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'action_name'));`

Answer (score 0):

Tow way I am Tested!

1.bootstrap file

```
$di->set('flash', function(){
    return new Phalcon\Flash\Session(array(
        'error' => 'alert alert-error',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
    ));
});
```

Control:

```
$this->flash->error('Some Message');
$this->response->redirect('signin/index');
```

View:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->flash->output();
?>
```

2.bootstrap file

```
$di->set('flash', function(){
        return new Phalcon\Flash\Direct(array(
            'error' => 'alert alert-error',
            'success' => 'alert alert-success',
            'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
        ));
    });
```

Control:

```
$this->flash->error('Jump to other page');
$this->dispatcher->forward(array('controller' => 'signin', 'action' => 'index'));
```

View:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getContent();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

In fact, our problem does not have anything to do with our **if ($_POST)** statement.

It is our view that causes this problem. To solve this issue, it is as easy as disabling the view before setting the flash message:

```
$this->view->disable();
$this->flash->error('Wrong credentials!');
$this->response->redirect('signin');
```

Answer (score 0):

two method:
use $this->flash->error('Some Message'); 
View:

getContent(); ?>

use $this->flashSession->error('Some Message'); 
View:

flashSession->output() ?>